# Steema TeeChart Pro installation error

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe8

When running the installer TeeChartVCLFMXSOURCE-2016.18.exe for Delphi XE8 on Windows 10, I get the following error:

Error running C:\Program Files (x86)\Steema Software\Steema TeeChart Pro VCL FMX Source Code 2016.18\TeeCalc\TeeCalc.exe 41875889903 94758366992696903 41827497462 2016.18 VCL 16573908 : 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\TMP149~1.BAT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

The installation can't continue after this.  I've tried running it as administrator.  Has anyone run into this?

Thanks for any help, Alan

Comment: As you're using the Pro version, you paid to purchase it. Have you contacted Steema for support regarding this issue? It's their installer.

Comment: Hello Ken,
I can’t reproduce the problema you’re experiencing installing the TeeChart V2016.18 under Windows 10. I would suggest you remove the C:\Program Files (x86)\Steema Software\Steema TeeChart Pro VCL FMX Source Code 2016.18
Then, run again the installer with administrator rights. Could you confirm your results? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @KenWhite It is the Pro version, our subscription has expired though so support or posting to their forums is unavailable.

Comment: @SandraPazos Tried that, no luck

Comment: Hello Alan,
Could you please send us an email to our Sales Dept at info at steema dot com because we can help you to fix the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @SandraPazos, done

Comment: Hello Alan,
I’m doing a monitoring of that problem. Could you tell us if you did the tests  we suggested? I remember the both suggestions
1- Try to download and install other TeeChart Pro VCL/FMX version, as example v2016.17. Could you confirm your results?
2- Could you try to install TeeChart Pro VCL/FMX v2016.18 in other machine? What results can you get?
Thanks in advance